# Interfacing current transformer to DSP

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement

I need to measure an AC current that of a flyback circuit with a peak of about 40A-50A at a frequency of 50 kHz on a 3.3V DSP. I figured out that the best way to do it is probably a current transformer, so I checked the available options and found the PAS6322.150NLT (aswell as the same transformer with other turn options), but I am unsure what the best way to connect it to my DSP is: I could use 2 resistors to build a voltage divider (or a precision voltage reference), add a burden resistor (what value does it need to be?) and then just connect it to an ADC pin of my DSP. Or I could use an OpAmp as transimpedance amplifier, but I am not sure if I need a voltage reference there aswell, and also I have no clue which resistor values to use there.

Comment: Hello and welcome. What are your accuracy requirements?  How frequently do you want to measure?

Comment: The measurement speed is basically continous and the DSP will take care of that, I just need to scale the output of the current transformer to a 0-3.3V signal. I am not sure about the accuracy requirements, it will be limited by the DSPs ADC resolution anyways.

Comment: @Jenny you will have to put hard numbers to the accuracy requirement. That's not "something the DSP will take care of"; that arises from your application's needs :) The point is that your ADC has an input impedance, and that affects measurements. How to work with that depends on how much effect you can tolerate.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I need the current sensing to detect certain points for controlling the flyback. I'd guess that something like 1% accuracy is enough, but I am really not sure and I don't know how I need to determine the requirements/put numbers on it. I know that the DSPIC33CK1024MP I am planning on using has onboard opamps aswell.